# JPQL for Entries Many To Many relationship

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have table with many to many relationship:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "book_category",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
                           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"))
private List<Category> categories;
```

What is the fastest method to find all `Books` which have selected category(by id).

Comment: What sort of a DAO are you using?

Comment: JPA. In DAOInterface i added method, that returns list of books

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use JPQL then try this:

```
select b
from Books b
  inner join b.categories c
where c.id = :id
```

Then in your repository:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(/* above query*/);
query.setInteger("id", 123);
query.list();
```

(If you are using JPA api then use `EntityManager` instead of Hiberantes `Session`)

Using a native query would be a bit more efficient as the JPQL has to make two joins, but you would loose the portability benefit.

On the side, you may need to use `DISTINCT` in the jpql query.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a jpql.

```
select b from Book b inner join fetch b.categories as c where c.id=:category_id
```

If you want just book ids, you can write a native sql query to query directly on the table 'book_category'